# Get the last 4 characters from a url and match with current year

Tags: javascript

1. Im trying to use Javascript to get the last 4 characters from my url that ends with something like this:

   ```
   http://myURL/schedule-2016/
   http://myURL/schedule-2017/
   ```
2. So I could use this conditional:

   ```
   var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
   var myurl = window.location.pathname;
   var lastFour = myurl.substr(myurl.length - 4);
   if(currentYear === lastFour){
   Something happens;
   }
   else{
   Something else happens;
   }
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: You problem don't want to compare a number to a string.

Comment: Very unclear question. Please edit it so others can help you more :)

Comment: getting the last 4 characters from `http://myURL/schedule-2016/` would give you `016/`

Comment: add .toString() to both

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to the number before comparing and also need to avoid `/` at the end if it contains.

```
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var myurl = window.location.pathname;
// replace the `/` at end then get the last 4 character
// parse it to Number
var lastFour = Number(myurl.replace(/\/$/,'').slice(-4));
if(currentYear === lastFour){
    // Something happens;
}
else{
    // Something else happens;
}
```

```js
var str1 = 'http://myURL/schedule-2016/',
  str2 = 'http://myURL/schedule-2017/';

function check(str) {
  var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  var lastFour = Number(str.replace(/\/$/, '').slice(-4));
  if (currentYear === lastFour) {
    console.log('equal');
  } else {
    console.log('not equal');
  }
}

check(str1);
check(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other fellows have already pointed out the main issues(casting to number and trimming trailing slash `/`).
I just wanted to suggest the additional alternative solution using `Number` constructor and `String.match` function:

```
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear(),
    lastFour = Number(location.pathname.match(/\d{4}(?=\/$)/));

if (currentYear === lastFour) {
   // Something happens;
} else {
   // Something else happens;
}
```